# Angular 4 - Track users logged-in state thoughout app to manipulate the view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The `Root App Component` within my app contains the main menu for the app. Now based on the whether the user is logged in or out I want the menu items to hide or show.

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

I have a `Authentication Service` which sends users login details to the API and the api verifies the user sends back a token and the token is saved within the `localStorage`

To check whether the user is authenticated while changing routes on the front-end I check the localStorage for the token:

**App Component:**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.isLoggedIn = this._authService.checkUserStatus();
}
```

**Authentication Service:**

```
checkUserStatus(){
  const user = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if(user){
    return true;
   }
}
```

I don't think this is the most efficient way of tracking a users logged in state throughout the app. Im looking for some professional advice on how I can achieve this.

**Question:**

How to track the users logged in state through out the app and use that to hide and show menu items?